# subgradient and subdifferential at the boundary of a closed set for discontinuous function.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, subgradient

Consider the function $ f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad$
$ f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2 & \text{if $x > 0$,} \\
1 & \text{if $x=0$.}
\end{cases} $

This function is convex. I want to find subdifferential at $x = 0$. Does it exist? Is it $\phi$ or something else?

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the empty set. You can visually see this from the epigraph; there's no non-vertical line supporting the epigraph at the point $(0, 1)$.

Applying the definition, suppose that $y \in \partial f(0)$. Then, for all $x \in (0, 1]$, we have,
$$yx = \langle y, x - 0 \rangle \le f(x) - f(0) = x^2 - 1.$$
As $x \to 0^+$, the left hand side tends to $0$, while the right hand side tends to $-1$. This contradicts the inequality above; eventually $yx - (x^2 - 1) \ge 0$ for $x$ sufficiently close to $0$.

Comment: I am completely convinced.Thanks